# How do I use my SQLite Query in my React Application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sqlite

Recently, I created a small react application that creates a quiz for the user to complete. However, I wanted to grab the questions from a database. Therefore, in VScode, I imported SQLite3, created a table, and wrote a simple query to test:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.db');
        db.serialize(()=>{
            db.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST");
            db.run("CREATE TABLE TEST (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)");
            db.run("INSERT INTO Test (name) VALUES ('Bob');");
            db.get("SELECT * FROM Test",(err,row)=>{
                console.log(row);
            });
        });
```

In the terminal, I ran `node data.js` and I got the value, `{ name: 'Bob' }` , as expected. Now that I have this data that I queried, how am I supposed to access this in my React App? Anytime I try to export this file or export the data, I just get an error. I feel really dumb here, and that I'm missing something obvious, as I just learned Node and SQLite.

Thanks

Comment: You have to create a route with express and  optional (controllers) to create an API, rest API. Then in react you can consume it with axios through HTTP methods in your case it would be a GET. So in your main node.js file `app.get('/', function(req, res) { //here you send your data with res.send
  res.send('hello world');
});`

Comment: React is for the UI. To access your database from your React App, you must implement your API using a backend framework such as Express . Then call your API with Axios or Fetch API to access your data.